# PrimeNg Inline Calendar not working in Dialog

Tags: html, angular, primeng

It seems like there is a bug with the primeng calendar (inline) component when used inside a  dialog component. Is this a known issue with a workaround?

[image]
In the left the calendar is instantiated in a regular component. In the right the calendar is instantiated inside a `<p-dialog>`

Taskcomponent:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" [inline]="true" [showWeek]="true" [style]="{'position': 'fixed', 'overflow': 'visible', 'z-index': '1201'}"></p-calendar>
```

Dialog code:

```
<p-dialog position="top-right" header="Neuer Task" [(visible)]="displayTask" [closeOnEscape]="false" showEffect="fade" [style]="{width: '30%', height: '50%'}" (onHide)="closeAction()" >
  <p class="line-height-3 m-0">
    <cd-task></cd-task>
  </p>
</p-dialog>
```

Comment: try removing position fixed, and z-index from styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it fixed by doing a little trick by adding an `*ngIf="displayTask"` to the calendar.

Comment: This hack worked for me too! Thanks for sharing.

My dialog code
```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayEditDialog" [modal]="true" [breakpoints]="{'960px': '30vw'}"  [style]="{width: '30vw' }" [draggable]="false" [resizable]="false" responsive="true" [transitionOptions]="'0ms'">
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512010/stefan)
Your hack worked for me too. I am using PrimeNG 12 and Angular 12, My dialog code

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="displayEditDialog" [modal]="true" 
          [breakpoints]="{'960px': '30vw'}"
          [style]="{width: '30vw' }" [draggable]="false" 
          [resizable]="false" 
          [transitionOptions]="'0ms'">
```

and for the calendar inside this modal

```
<p-calendar *ngIf="displayEditDialog" appendTo="body" ...></p-calendar>
```